# How to sort objects by different variables?

Tags: java, sorting, comparable, compareto

Can I use a compareTo() method with a second argument to sort objects by different variables, or should I use some other method?

For example:

```
public class Girl implements Comparable<Girl> {

    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private int hotness;

    public Girl () {} // blah blah constructor

    @Override
    public int compareTo (Girl g, int order) {
        if (order == 1) // then sort by first name
        if (order == 2) // then sort by last name
        if (order == 3) // then sort by hotness
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case it is better if you use Comparator

Comment: An important point to remember is that comparisons must agree in both directions, so you'd have to use the `order` attribute of the other object too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. You'll find that code doesn't compile -- the `@Override` annotation says that `compareTo(Girl, int)` must be declared in a superclass or interface, but it's not! `Comparable<Girl>` defines only `compareTo(Girl)`.

Instead, you should use a `Comparator<Girl>` for each ordering. This is a class that provides its own `compareTo` that takes two girls. You can then create different comparators, and pass the appropriate one to the function that needs it. In other words, remove the `order` field from `Girl`, and instead implement the different orderings as different instances of a `Comparator<Girl>`.

Most classes or functions that take a `T extends Comparable<T>` also have versions that take a `T` *and* a `Comparator<T>`. One example of this is [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29). Another is [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29), which can take a comparator at construction time.

If that seems annoying or pedantic, think about how you would use such a function. Let's say your function takes a `T extends Comparable<T>`. You try to compare two of these by calling `item1.compareTo(item2)`, according to that `Comparable` interface. If your code compiled, that method wouldn't exist! Note that Java doesn't have default parameters, so there's no way to say "if they don't pass in the `int order`, assume it's 0."

Answer (score 1):

You are not overriding the `compareTo` method, but overloading it. And marking with `@Override` won't allow to compile the class.

Use multiple `Comparator` classes to compare `Girls` based on dirrent scenarios.

Comment: +1 for the instance variable although you should show it as a parameter when constructing the class.

Comment: -1 This is actually a very dangerous idea, and it violates the `Comparable` contract. What if you have one girl instantiated with `order = 1`, and a second one `order = 2`? In that case, you could have `girl1.compareTo(girl2) > 0` _and_ `girl2.compareTo(girl1) > 0`. This means that there is not a [total ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_ordering) on `Girl`, which the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface requires. A lot of code will likely break.

Comment: I agree with @yshavit. I take back my upvote (if I could). I thought the code was creating a custom comparator. I wasn't wearing my glasses :)

Comment: @Yshavit : He won't use `order` to compare the `Girls`, it's only used as a base for comparing. whether need to be sorted with `fname` or `lname`.

Comment: Imagine `ada = new Girl("Ada", "Lovelace", 2)` and `frances = new Girl("Frances E.", "Allen", 1)`. `ada.compareTo(frances)` will use Amanda's ordering of last name, meaning that it will return `> 0` ("Lovelace" comes after "Allen"). `frances.compareTo(ada)` will use Frances' ordering of first name, meaning it will also return `> 0` ("Frances" comes after "Ada").

Comment: Sorry, but it is _not_ a correct way. It violates an important part of the `Comparable` contract, which is that the comparison imposes a _total_ ordering. Your code does not. Neither does the OP's original code (if it compiled), but the OP also asked whether they should use some other method. They should, and that other method is a `Comparator`.

Comment: No worries! Comparison (and equality) can be tricky because of edge cases such as these. I recognized this because I've run across it before. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, what you're trying to do won't work, as you're not overriding the `compareTo()` method. An alternate solution here can be to use `Collections.sort()` to sort your collections with a custom comparator and use the `order` variable in it(it has to be made `final` to be able to use it in that). Something like this.

```
void inSomeMethod() {
    final int order = 0; // has to be final
    Collections.sort(new ArrayList<Girl>(), new Comparator<Girl>() { // for example

        @Override
        public int compare(Girl o1, Girl o2) {
            if (order == 1) // then sort by first name
            if (order == 2) // then sort by last name
            if (order == 3) // then sort by hotness
            return 0;
        }
    });
}
```